# Netlify can't install forked npm module: Could not fetch metadata

Tags: typescript, npm, netlify

So I forked and modified `g-sheets-api` module. This is my version: https://github.com/lpares12/g-sheets-api

Then I have installed with the following command in my web project:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/lpares12/g-sheets-api.git --save-dev
```

And whenever I upload the project into Netlify, it fails:

```
8:30:02 PM: Installing npm packages using npm version 8.19.3
8:30:02 PM: npm WARN old lockfile
8:30:02 PM: npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
8:30:02 PM: npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
8:30:02 PM: npm WARN old lockfile
8:30:02 PM: npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
8:30:02 PM: npm WARN old lockfile
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile Error: git dep preparation failed
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:63:27)
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile  Could not fetch metadata for g-sheets-api@git+ssh://git@github.com/lpares12/g-sheets-api.git#4e8ec12a4654d29421b131ddfe4bcff540589cc8 Error: git dep preparation failed
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:63:27)
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5) {
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile   cmd: '/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/node',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile   args: [
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'install',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--force',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--cache=/opt/buildhome/.npm',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--prefer-offline=false',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--prefer-online=false',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--offline=false',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--no-progress',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--no-save',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--no-audit',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--include=dev',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--include=peer',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--include=optional',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--no-package-lock-only',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '--no-dry-run'
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile   ],
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile   code: 127,
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile   signal: null,
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile   stdout: '\n> g-sheets-api@2.1.3 prepublish\n> tsc\n\n',
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile   stderr: 'npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See
```

Also, I see lots of errors of this kind too:

```
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'sh: 1: tsc: not found\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm ERR! code 127\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm ERR! path /opt/buildhome/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneDqwPak\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm ERR! command failed\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm ERR! command sh -c -- tsc\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     '\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile     'npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-02-28T19_30_05_045Z-debug-0.log\n'
8:30:19 PM: npm WARN old lockfile }
8:30:26 PM: npm ERR! code 127
8:30:26 PM: npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
8:30:26 PM: npm ERR! command /opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/node /opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/opt/buildhome/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
8:30:26 PM: npm ERR! > g-sheets-api@2.1.3 prepublish
8:30:26 PM: npm ERR! > tsc
```

Not sure what I did wrong with this, and its a bit difficult to follow the track at that output. Whenever I run `npm run dev` or `npm run build` in my project, works correclty. I can see that the `package-lock.json` of my deployed app has the following:

```
    "g-sheets-api": { 
      "version": "git+https://github.com/lpares12/g-sheets-api.git#4e8ec12a4654d29421b131ddfe4bcff540589cc8", 
      "from": "git+https://github.com/lpares12/g-sheets-api.git", 
      "dev": true, 
      "requires": { 
        "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5" 
      } 
    }
```

So I can cleary see this commit exists and it is public. Any help would be appreciated.

In case it is relevant, I'm using Netlify, Vite and Typescript, in case it is relevant.

Comment: Try adding `tsc` and `typescript` as dev dependencies to your github package.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev For `typescript` I can do `npm install typescript --save-dev`, but for `tsc`? What's the proper way?

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the module `g-sheets-api` requiring `tsc` but not declaring it as a dependency (or devdependency) in `package.json`.

Since it is not automatically installed via npm, it fails to run.

Adding it to `package.json` is the preferred solution.

Changing it to `npx tsc` is also an option, but it makes the package management lifecycle convoluted and will not work on isolated build systems.

Comment: I tried to add `npm install tsc --save-dev` but when running in Netlify it said something like: "tsc is not the command you are looking for". So finally I tried the `npx tsc` thing and pushed the updated build directory in my fork and worked.

Comment: I wonder how is it working with the normal package, if they don't have tsc either...

Comment: @lpares12 `tsc` is provided by `typescript`. The `tsc` package does nothing.

Comment: So when you said "install tsc" you meant `npm install typescript --save-dev`?

Comment: I meant adding typescript to package.json of your forked depedency. Adding to your rooot project works too, however.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by running the following commands in the forked module:

```
npm install typescript --save-dev
npx tsc
```

And then pushing the `build` folder to github.

I really don't understand how this worked, so leaving this open in case someone can clarify a bit.